# Mysqldump connecting issue

Tags: database, backup, mysql

I'm trying to make dump with next command:

> mysqldump -v -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3308 -x --add-drop-table
>   --add-locks --create-options -K -e -q -A > database.sql

The result (after password input) is message "Connecting to 127.0.0.1...". After this is nothing (no any errors, just waiting).

database.sql is empty file.

Why I see no any activity? Is it bug?

Answer (score 0):

From http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mysqldump1.html

> The password to use when connecting to the server. If you use the
>   short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and
>   the password. If you omit the password value following the --password
>   or -p option on the command line, you are prompted for one.

The system may be waiting for you to input a password.

If you want to avoid that just add the password in the command. Assuming your password is "FLOWER":

```
mysqldump -v -u root -pFLOWER -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3308 -x --add-drop-table --add-locks --create-options -K -e -q -A > database.sql
```

Comment: Thank you for response, Sebastien!

Look at the question, it says that the message is showed after password input.

Comment: I tried to use "-pPASSWORD" or "-p" and input password after request. But it has same effect: "Connecting to 127.0.0.1..."

Comment: Yes. It has no efect.

Answer (score 0):

This problem, as you describe it, can be caused by the mysql server not running or not being available on the host (in your case, localhost), or it is running but not on that port.

What kind of a system is it? If it is a flavor of linux/unix, you can run

```
ps -ef|egrep mysql
```

to see if the mysql server is running. Check the equivalent command on Windows or whatever else you may be running. Also, you can verify that this is the problem by seeing if this works:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3308
```

The solution is to start the server:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

or the equivalent on your system.

Note: if it is running, determine what port it is on - it is possible that you are not specifying the right port number. The default is 3306 - it is unusual that you are using a non-standard port.

Comment: ps -ef|egrep mysql: 

root      1653     1  0 Oct10 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr                     /bin/mysqld_safe
mysql     1785  1653 69 Oct10 ?        11-08:55:39 /usr/sbin                     /mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/home/db-mysql --user=mysql                      --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mys                     qld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
admuser   6562  6545  0 22:43 pts/0    00:00:00 egrep mysql

Comment: mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 is ok, but mysqldump -v -u root -pPASSWORD -h 127.0.0.1 -x --add-drop-table --add-locks --create-options -K -e -q -A | gzip -c > db_03_11_13.gz shows only message "-- Connecting to 127.0.0.1..."